# Overfull hbox in tabular

Tags: tables, line-breaking, boxes, warnings

In the following (M)WE, the `tabular` version of the Contact information from a CV gives an overfull hbox warning when compiled with `pdfLatex`, but the `minipage` version does not. Why? I have not found a satisfactory explanation among the many questions that have been posed about overfull hboxes, but if you know the right place, please direct me there!

```
\documentclass[10pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,
            margin=1in,
            showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{2.1in}%
\newlength{\spacewidth}\setlength{\spacewidth}{50pt}%
\newlength{\lcollength}\setlength{\lcollength}{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}
%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\lcollength}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}}%
\parbox{\lcollength}{%
Department of Mechanical Engineering\\%
University of Anywhere\\%
123 Road St.\\%
Normal, IL USA}%
&%
{\vrule width 0.5pt}
\parbox[m][4\baselineskip]{\spacewidth}{}%
&%
\parbox{\rcollength}{%
\textit{E-mail:}\\%
\textit{Work:} +1-123-456-7890 \\%
\textit{Cell:} +1-123-456-7890 \\%
\textit{Web:}%
}%
\end{tabular}%

\begin{minipage}{\lcollength}
Department of Mechanical Engineering\\%
University of Anywhere\\%
123 Road St.\\%
Normal, IL USA%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\spacewidth}
\rule{0.5pt}{4\baselineskip}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\rcollength}
\textit{E-mail:}\\%
\textit{Work:} +1-123-456-7890 \\%
\textit{Cell:} +1-123-456-7890 \\%
\textit{Web:}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\lcollength}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}}%
```

you have used `@{}` to omit most inter-column space but you do not have `@{}` at the end so there is a `\tabcolsep` after the last column.

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\lcollength}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}@{}}%
```

Comment: Thanks! Why does LaTeX put a `\tabcolsep` before the first column and after the last column? Or, another way, why is `\tabcolsep` used as the pre- and post-table spacing?

Comment: @darthbith _why_ hard to answer You'd have to ask Leslie if he can remember if other options were considered, LaTeX has always done this.

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438820/overfull-vbox-in-list-of-abbreviations maybe you could help me too :)